# How to create a default login user account when seeding users?

Tags: laravel

I want a way to have a "default login" so that when I do a `php artisan migrate:refresh` on my database I can seed a bunch of users in PLUS have a user account with the same email and password everytime. What is the best way of achieving this? I thought maybe having the standard user factory plus creating a Default user factory would work but since it's using the same User class it just creates a new standard user.

**UserFactory.php**

```
/** @var \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory $factory */

use App\User;
use Faker\Generator as Faker;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;


$factory->define(User::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'email' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
        'email_verified_at' => now(),
        'password' => '$2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC/.og/at2.uheWG/igi', // password
        'remember_token' => Str::random(10),
    ];
});
```

**DefaultUserFactory.php**

```
/** @var \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory $factory */

use App\User;
use Faker\Generator as Faker;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

$factory->define(User::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
         'name' => $faker->name,
         'email' => 'test@demo.com',
         'email_verified_at' => now(),
         'password' => bcrypt('demo123'), // password
         'remember_token' => Str::random(10),
    ];
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `UserSeeder.php` create a default user (using your factory) just before you seed your other users:

```
public function run()
{
  // Create admin user
  $user = factory(User::class)->create([
    'name' => 'AdMiN',
    'email' => 'admin@admin.com',
    'password' => bcrypt('aDmIn'),
  ]);

  // Create 5 more users:
  factory(User::class, 5)->create();
}
```

**Note**: The `create()` method from factories can take an array of attributes. These will overwrite the definitions from the factory.

Make sure to activate/run this seeder in your `DatabaseSeeder.php`:

```
public function run()
{
  $this->call(UserSeeder::class);
}
```

Edit: there should be no need for your `DefaultUserFactory.php`, everything can be handled via your `UserFactory.php`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [seeder](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/seeding), and import a specific user.

a. You run `php artisan make:seeder CreateUser`

b. Insert in the run() method the data for the user you need to create, i.e.

```
    User::create([
         'name' => 'Sample Name',
         'email' => 'test@demo.com',
         'email_verified_at' => now(),
         'password' => bcrypt('demo123'), // password
         'remember_token' => Str::random(10),
    ]);
```

c. You run each time you run migration `php artisan db:seed --class= CreateUser`

Answer (score 0):

Just create an account before seeding your database. `php artisan migrate:refresh` you gonna have to use another method `migrate:refresh` flushes out your database before filling it with fake user. try this `php artisan migrate:refresh --step=5`
 with the right step for your situation.